# Load plugin by default for every Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, plugins

Is there a way to load a plugin by default for every `new Vue()`?

I use a library that creates it's own Vue and I need it to have a plugin included to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vue.component('my-component-name', {
  // ... options ...
})
```

These components are globally registered. That means they can be used in the template of any root Vue instance (new Vue) created after registration.

More information in the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration).